# how to use vee-validate on vue-select tool?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to validate a select field component provided by `vue-select` tool using `vee-validate`.
I tried this

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="form_category ">Category <small>*</small></label>
    <v-select :options="categories " v-validate="'required'" data-vv-name="category" v-model="campaign.category " class="form-control " id="form_category "></v-select>
</div>
<div v-show="errors.has('category')" class="error-box fr ">{{ errors.first('category') }}</div>
```

In the [`vee-validate` documentation](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/examples.html#component-example) they ask to add `data-vv-name="name"`. I added it to the parent component but the problem is that `vue-select` is not given any name to the `input field`.